# How to replace angular component tag after rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Lets say we have a angular component with selector "grid"?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'grid',
  template: '<div>This is a grid.</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
})
```

Now when we use this grid inside another component, we do the following.

```
    <p>This is another component.</p>
    <div>
    <grid></grid>
    <grid></grid>
    <grid></grid>
    <grid></grid>
    </div>
```

When this is finally rendered. The html looks like following.

```
<p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<grid><div>This is a grid.</div></grid>
<grid><div>This is a grid.</div></grid>
<grid><div>This is a grid.</div></grid>
<grid><div>This is a grid.</div></grid>
</div>
```

Now, I don't want a grid tag here. Instead I want just the following.

```
<p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div>This is a grid.</div>
<div>This is a grid.</div>
<div>This is a grid.</div>
<div>This is a grid.</div>
</div>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Even though you could do this with javascript (find an element, take all its children, remove it, and place the children in the parent of the removed element) I don't think it's possible, or desirable in Angular. I don't see how Angular could keep track of that component. If what you want is to avoid the repetition of elements, simply don't place a "div" inside and style the host element (grid) directly with :host

Comment: Are you trying to clone the div?

Answer (score 4):

You use an attribute selector when you don't want to use a DOM tag.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[grid]',
  template: '<div>This is a grid.</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
})
```

Then in the template:

```
<p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div grid></div>
</div>
```

Which becomes this after rendering:

```
<p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div grid><div>This is a grid.</div></div>
</div>
```

This is generally how you use components inside a `<table>` structure. For example; you might want to apply a component to a `<td>` element.

If you need *structural* HTML elements inside your component, but do not want them part of the rendered HTML, then you use a `<ng-container>`. This is a special DOM element that is part of the component, but not part of the DOM rendered result.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[grid]',
  template: '<ng-container>This is a grid.</ng-container>',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
})
```

Which becomes this after rendering:

```
<p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div grid>This is a grid.</div>
</div>
```

You can use `<ng-container>` to apply structural directives like `*ngIf` to the *outer* parts of HTML without having to add unwanted HTML.

Comment: as a side note, if you want to force developers to use a div for this component, you can write : `selector: 'div[grid]'`

Comment: I edited my question. I don't want to use attribute selector. I want my output to look exactly like above.

Comment: @coolswastik you don't want the div to have `grid` as a property ? If so, why ?

Comment: If I use grid as a  property . It will render following html. <p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div ><div>This is a grid.</div></div>
</div> But. I want following html. <p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div>This is a grid.</div>
</div>

Comment: @coolswastik in your `grid` template, remove your <div> element ! :)

Comment: This is just a sample html. My use case is pretty complicated in which a tag needs to exactly beneath the other tag. I am looking for something equivalent to directive replacement in angular js, in which we can set replace: true.

Comment: Use ng-container instead of div

Comment: I have already thought about it and tried it. It does not work. @Chellappan

Comment: @coolswastik I think I understand, and have updated my answer to include `<ng-container>`. You still need to use an attribute selector, but it's possible to match the exact HTML output that you want.

Comment: :( . This still does not solve my problem. I want a div tag in my component. adding ng-container does not solve my problem. :(

Comment: @coolswastik Angular is a web component framework, and follows the specifications. Components are custom DOM elements and what you're asking for isn't consistent with that description. Here's the specs: https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/components#w3c_all

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector

```
<p>This is another component.</p>
<div>
<div grid></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible with ViewContainerRef
Suppose you have component A

```
@Component({
 selector: 'a-comp',
  template: `
  <span>I am A component</span>`,
   })
  export class AComponent {
  }
```

And then register it with in the declarations and entryComponents in app module

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule],
 declarations: [AppComponent,       AComponent],
 entryComponents: [AComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule {
   }
```

And then in the parent App component we put the code that creates A component instance and inserts it

```
@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>I am parent App component</h1>
  <div class="insert-a-component-    inside">
      <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
      </div>
     `,
     })
    export class AppComponent {
     @ViewChild('vc', {read:        ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

     constructor(private r:       ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

     ngAfterViewInit() {
     const factory =    this.r.resolveComponentFactory(AComponent);
     this.vc.createComponent(factory);
     }
     }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This introduced an additional div component for ng-container.